# Solve equation with variable in exponent as well as base

Tags: exponentiation

I'm having a bad brain blockade right now... I'm trying to solve the following equation for $n$:

$$PV=\frac{FV}{\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution in closed form in terms of the familiar functions of (say) 1st-year calculus (polynomials, trig functions, logs, exponentials, square roots, cube roots, etc., etc.).